# Tableau, color-coded bar chart not working

Tags: tableau-api, calculated-field

Public workbook [here](https://public.tableau.com/profile/sonihal#!/vizhome/NumericBusinessRatings/Products). Source is Excel file.

I was able to create ordered bar chart based on (1) Location (2) Product

[image]

When I drag `Above Three` into Color, the graph is incorrect, how to troubleshoot?

[image]

#### Update

I made change such that `Calculation` computers based on Product, Above Three for each Location, at level Product.

[image]

However, Morton's still shows error.

The order in Mortons should descend, based on number of records, i.e.

1. Dark Chocolate
2. Beer
3. Toffee
4. Coffee
5. Fries

Rest of the Locations are correct, but only Mortons gives out-of-order products

[image]

#### Update2

Calculated Field `Calculation3 = Index()`

And I filter `Calculation3` for 1 to 3, to display top 3 products

If I remove `Calculation3` from filter, it gives correct order but it give ALL products, not the top three popular products (per Location).

I updated [workbook](https://public.tableau.com/profile/sonihal#!/vizhome/NumericBusinessRatings/Top3perLocationwithRating) to illustrate this. Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the purpose of the Index() field but that is creating your issue. Remove it from rows and the color appears to work the way you want it.

Comment: Index() is to create a table calculation in tab `Table Calculation`. To find % of `Above Three` rating per location.

Comment: When I open your workbook with Tableau 9.1.1 Desktop, I get the colors in the format you describe. Perhaps that's a bug in Public?

Comment: @davidski actually I made modifications (sorry I didn't update). but there is still error under `Mortons`. Will update question shortly.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you are looking for

[image: Tableau Table calculation]

I have also published the file at the below address. You can take a view on that.

[Tableau Wokbook](https://public.tableau.com/profile/publish/NumericBusinessRatings_1/Top3perLocationwithRating)

I achieved it by the following methods.

[image: Table Calc]

I changed the Calculation 3 field from Index() to RANK(SUM(NUMBER OF RECORDS)). 
The calculation 3 was kept in between Location and period then edited the table calculation of calculation 3 by keeping the Addressing of the edit table calculation,  having only the location and product as shown below and then Set the restarting every to Product.

You can check the workbook for more information

Comment: When I remove `Product`, it removes the labels. And I still get error with `Mortons` :(

Comment: can you please upload your workbook in tableau 8.3 format? I dont have tableau 9 and hence not able to work with your workbook

Comment: When I go to download page, it gives version 9.1x, `http://www.tableau.com/products`. How to upload in 8.3 format?

Comment: not a problem, check my solution... i have updated it

Comment: Actually all the data is out-of-order. I'll research RANK approach